# Exposing REST methods in spring boot

Tags: rest, spring-boot

I am writing a microservice in spring boot. I wanted to ask the community if there was easy out of the box way to expose REST methods to a HAL-like browser. 
I should be able to control what is exposed and also be able to hook some sort of authentication.

Tried a bit of googling but couldn't come with something quick and easy.

Thanks,
Jubin

Answer (score 0):

By executing the [cURL command](http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/how-to-test-a-rest-api-from-command-line-with-curl/), say `$ curl -i http://localhost:8080` you should get the output, which shows the HAL+JSON type format. If you want to use the browser, I suggest that you use Google Chrome and install the JSONView
add-on. If you do so, you can see the HAL+JSON type in your browser. Safri and F-fox have the same plugin/ add-on, but it doesn’t work properly all the time

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8080

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Sun, 23 Oct 2016 00:12:29 GMT
{
"_links" : {
"yourPage" : {
"href" : "http://localhost:8080/yourPage{?page,size,sort}",
"templated" : true
},
"profile" : {
"href" : "http://localhost:8080/profile"
}
}
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for a spring-boot package which creates the HTML interface out-of-the box interface.

Comment: Try this  : http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_the_hal_browser